# will the global variable inside a script visible to another script which share same environment

Tags: powershell, scope

so, I have two scripts (`a.ps1` and `b.ps1`) inside another scripts (`c.ps1`). `c.ps1` will only do the calling of other two scripts (`a.ps1` & `b.ps1`). If I declare a global variable inside of `a.ps1` and I want to use that global variable inside of `b.ps1`.  Is it going to work since both scripts (`a.ps1` & `b.ps1`) are in the same environment (`c.ps1`)?

Comment: In a powershell session: help about_scope. See the examples given.

Comment: Try it and find out. This is a simple test case.

Comment: I tested myself this morning, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you well, actually you have only one script "c" and "a" and "b" are acting as functions inside "c". 
In this case the answer is: Yes, if you declare variable in first function "a" you can use it in the second function "c".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did the tests myself and can say: it depends on how you start one script from another. If you use something like `Start-Process powershell -args "-file a.ps1"` a global variable will not be passed. But if you use `& .\a.ps1` it will be. For example:

c.ps1:

```
& .\a.ps1
```

a.ps1:

```
$global:TestVariable = "TEST"
& .\b.ps1
```

b.ps1:

```
Write-Host "Test variable: [$global:TestVariable]."
Read-Host # for pause
```

In this case the output will be:

```
D:\TEST_123>powershell -file c.ps1
Test variable: [TEST].
```

---

And as mentioned by @David Brabant you should read [about_scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) man.